# Android: Pressing Back (and orientation change) causes hang after implementing onPause

Tags: android, orientation, back, freeze, onpause

So I manage to get my program to lose focus when pressing the Home button and successfully bring the activity back when resuming, unfortunately the method I'm using causes the Thread to hang when the screen changes in a matter that it doesn't lose focus immediately.

EDITTED -- Placed onResume into main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = true;
    }
    return;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = false;
        mPauseLock.notifyAll();
    }
}

public class ThreadClass extends Thread
{
    boolean isRunning;
    public void BeginThread()
    {

        if (mGameIsRunning) {
            onResume();
        }else{
            if(isRunning)return;
            isRunning=true;
            start();
            mGameIsRunning=true;
        }
    }



    public void run()
    {
        Canvas canvas;
        while(isRunning)
        {
            canvas=null;
            try
            {
                canvas = canvasClass.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (canvasClass.surfaceHolder)
                {
                    //processClass.processGame();
                    canvasClass.onDraw(canvas);
                }
            }finally{
                if(canvas!=null)
                {
                    canvasClass.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            synchronized (mPauseLock)
            {
                while (mPaused)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

What has to be changed so that the activity will pause when pressing Home and be thrown out of the stack when pressing Back? Also as explained, the same issue happens when screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the onResume is inside the thread class?
If that's the actual code, remove it to the activity class.
Rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: Well it was in the activity class at first I was just yelling at the wind, it doesn't seem to make a difference either way. Still hangs on screen changes other than pressing Home/pausing. EDITTED: Updated code